Camera not working after 24.04 update
Neither Cheese nor Snapshot camera are getting my inbuilt webcam is just saying no camera/device found, I also try in google meet butthere is also saying no camera found.

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! USB camera should be listed in the 'lsusb' command in terminal.

Yes. Please add the output of lsusb with an edit to the question.

Did it work before upgrading to 24.04? Did it stop working after some update? Silly question: Did you restart after the update?

Yes my camera is working well in older versions and Yes I restart after the update

This is what come after the Isusb command:-
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub-----
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. Bluetooth wireless interface-------
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
